# What is the meaning of AWESOME_SERVICE_API_TOKEN in pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

pm2 json app declaration has an env entry as below

```
"env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "production",
    "AWESOME_SERVICE_API_TOKEN": "xxx"
  }
```

What does `AWESOME_SERVICE_API_TOKEN` means here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AWESOME_SERVICE_API_TOKEN` is just an example. You can define any parameters that you need in your application, see [here](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/b2455cb44013a11c73525f9d4c7e3691602c7198/ADVANCED_README.md#json-app-declaration).
In your app you can access the `NODE_ENV` or `AWESOME_SERVICE_API_TOKEN` values to do whatever you want.